# Updating hash map value android firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap, setvalue

Trying to update values using a hash map in android studio.
The values are passed through from a another activity.
databaseReference.setValue is used to update the values. 
I have also tried updateChildren.

```
       EditLogbookBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Logbook").push();
            //Data will be saved in "Logbook" node.
            Map<String, Object> updatemap = new HashMap<>();
            updatemap.put("id", databaseReference.getKey());
            updatemap.put("Uid", uId);
            updatemap.put("picName", EditPicNamePost);
            updatemap.put("makeModel", EditMakeModelPost);
            updatemap.put("ident", EditIdentPost);
            updatemap.put("duration", EditDurationPost);
            updatemap.put("date", EditDatePost); //calendar
            updatemap.put("remarks", EditRemarksPost);
            updatemap.put("singleEngine", EditSingleEnginePost);
            updatemap.put("picTime", EditpicTimePost);
            updatemap.put("dualTime", EditdualTimePost);
            updatemap.put("weather", EditWeatherPost);

            updatemap.put("from", EditDeparture);
            updatemap.put("to", EditDestination);
            updatemap.put("landingsDay", EditLandingsDaySpinner);
            updatemap.put("landingsNight", EditLandingsNightSpinner);

            updatemap.put("deptTime", editDeptTime);
            updatemap.put("destTime", editdestTime);

            databaseReference.setValue(updatemap);

        }


    });
```

Comment: so what do you want ? What is your question ?

Comment: Is there something I am doing wrong in the code? When I click on the edit button, it does not update the values. The hash map is attached.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Instead include the actual code in your question, this makes it searchable and it can be used in a possible answer. You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50533049/edit) button below your question.

Comment: i think this should work for u. check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listner to databaseReference. This will help you to know why data is not updating.

```
databaseReference.setValue(updatemap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() 
{
@Override
public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) 
{
// Values Updated
}
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of Set value you should use updateChildren method....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).